# React native / Android livestream player

Tags: android, react-native, http-live-streaming, live-streaming

I'm looking for a livestream player able to read a H264 stream (or any video livestream). I found the react-native-video [https://github.com/brentvatne/react-native-video]. But it doesn't say if it can read a livestream.

The livestream i have is broudcasted via the camera of a Raspberry Pi. I can encode the stream in soemthing else if needed for a potential solution.

I have tried finding livestream players, but i can't really find any, or they all want to stream the camera of the android device, and not READ a stream.

If you have an Android solution for this, i will try and implement a react-native component for it.

Thank you all :)

Comment: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer use this player for livestream

Comment: Did you get any solution of this?

Comment: Did you get any solutions ? @GClovs and OP ? Thanks.

Comment: NOTE: ExoPlayer does not support RTSP as of writting: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/55

Comment: Have you found a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 options for you:

- https://github.com/xeodou/react-native-player - is using ExoPlayer inside, haven't tested it (using RN 0.13)
- https://github.com/sejoker/react-native-android-vitamio - based on VitamIO, could be run on RN 0.21, it could run stream video, but functionality is fairly limited